# How can I filter by priority on the taskboard in DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps in **Boards > Sprints** you have different options to look at a sprint.

When you're in **Taskboard** view there's a filter button, that allows you to filter by: "Types", "Assigned to", "States", "Tags", and "Area". Where's the "Priority" option?

Answer (score 1):

> When you're in Taskboard view there's a filter button, that allows you
>   to filter by: "Types", "Assigned to", "States", "Tags", and "Area".
>   Where's the "Priority" option?

1.Sorry but as I know `Priority` is not a supported filter option in TaskBoard for now. Maybe you can try using [Style Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/customize-cards?view=azure-devops#define-style-rules-to-highlight-cards) to highlight the important Items as a temporary workaround.

(Style rules can't filter the cards actually, but it helps us to distinct Priority levels easily.)

[image]

2.Also, feel free to post a feature request in our [User Voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) to share your feedback about our product. I too think it's a good idea to add the `Priority` into filter option!

After that you can share the feedback link in this case, members interested in that can vote for you and product team would raise its priority if it gets more votes. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll do the user voice forum thing.

Comment: @VictorAnzala That's great! Share the link in this issue and members here can vote for you/

Comment: Here it is: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/976091/filter-by-priority-on-the-taskboard.html

Comment: The team would consider it seriously if it gets enough votes. Thanks for your suggestion to make our product better :)

Comment: How can this feature request only have 22 votes two years later ?  Everyone reading this - please add your vote.

Answer (score 1):

The best workaround I've found so far is to type the number on the "Filter by keyword" field. If you put 1 for example, you will see all the tasks with priority 1 and all the tasks that have a 1 in their title.

Answer (score 0):

you could edit the cards (click on gear in the board), and in Cards > Fields, add an additional field called priority.  Now, if priority is only a number, then if you filter on 2, then you'll see priority 2, titles that include 2 (like 'application app-b2c-registration doesn't work'), and ticket numbers that have 2 in it like 53214.  Not ideal!

One possibility would be to edit the priority values, which might not be immediately possible, but create a new field called like priority2 and put non-integer values like 1 - gigahigh, 2 - megahigh, 3 - kilohigh, 4 - high, 5 - medium, 6 - (you get the picture)

then hide the original priority and add your new priority2.

then back in your board, ensure priority2 is on the card, and you can then filter out by typing in 1 - or gigahigh, 2 - or megahigh, etc.

Not the greatest solution I know, would be great if you can just edit the filter options, but AFAIK you can't.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need the priority field sorted cause in the Sprint backlog you determine the importance of the work items by the order in which they appear, the upper work items are the most important ones.

You can change the order by drag and drop work items from one location to another.

[Sprint backlog work item importance by order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTcza.png)